# Accessing bean defined in jaxrs:serviceBeans section of Spring XML config file in JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf

I'm trying to access `MyBean` from the following Spring configuration XML snippet in my integration test:

```
<jaxrs:server name="myResource" address="foo">
  <jaxrs:serviceBeans>        
    <bean id="myBean" class="com.example.bar.MyBean" />
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  <jaxrs:providers>
    <!-- ... -->
  </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

My test looks like this:

```
@Resource(name = "myBean")
MyBean b;
//...
```

When I run it, I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.Test': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myBean' is defined
```

Adding the `id` to the bean above didn't help (I used `@Autowired` before).

How can I access that bean from the `jaxrs:serviceBean` section in my test?

Comment: Didnt find any answer either out of creating a server and testing the requests directly...
https://www.callibrity.com/blog/jax-rs-integration-testing-with-apache-cxf